# Wrap variable in quotes

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I have a flask application that takes what a user types into a form and then adds a little bit extra and passes this as variables in another script.
For example:

```
session['search'] = '--q ' + request.args.get('search_key')
```

which would the run a script I have with that on the end so when user types " abc " this is passed;

```
example.py --q abc
```

what i would like to do is allow for spaces so user types " d e f " this would be passed;

```
example.py --q "d e f"
```

Is this possible to achieve? At the moment the python script `example.py` takes the space as moving onto next argument.
Currently when i include "" the word 'search' is sent instead of what the user has put in the form.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo, actually, that's **not** the best-practices approach. The right way to do things is to not involve a shell while invoking a subprocess at all, and thus not _need_ quotes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that's why I've posted a comment only and not an answer. OP might have some reasons to use shell but it's hard to assess with such a poor code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you running the second script?

If you do it the right way, you won't invoke a shell at all, so you don't need to add quotes (which are used *by shells* to decide how to split arguments into an `argv` array), and instead can pass the exact argv array you want.

For instance:

```
subprocess.Popen(['example.py', '--q', request.args.get('search_key', '')])
```

No quotes added, but no quotes needed -- the result from `request.args.get('search_key, '')` is passed as a single argument. Note that this only works if you **do not pass `shell=True`**.

See the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess) documentation for details -- on collecting stdout and stderr, checking exit status, and much more.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
in_text = '"'+str(input('Enter arg: '))+'"'
session['search'] = '--q ' + request.args.get(in_text)
```

Basically, it takes in the user input as a string and adds a `"` at the start and end:

```
>>> a = '"'+str(input('In: '))+'"'
In: hello
>>> a
'"hello"'
>>> print a
"hello"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but want to stay clear of using the terminal as will access from remote webpage. Thanks for the effort